# Custom excerpt length on home page

Tags: excerpt

I thought that I got this working but unfortunately it is not. I need my static home page to have an excerpt length of 50 and every other pages to have one of 20. Here is my code so far:

```
function custom_excerpt_length( $length ) {
   if(is_front_page()) $content='excerpt';
   return 50;
}

add_filter( 'excerpt_length', 'custom_excerpt_length', 999 );
```

I can tell it's not working because on seamlessthemes.com the excerpt is 50, but on seamlessthemes.com/themes the excerpt is still 50. Please note this theme had a default one of 20 for some reason, so the themes page should still be 20.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you the author of those child themes?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. I have made thematic child themes before though if thats what you meant.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### How filters work

Filters are simply a **point** where you can take some value, that is set (for something) in core (for e.g. the `the_excerpt()` function), in open to modifications.

So...

```
$some_var = apply_filters( 'change_this_var', 50 );
```

...just says:

> »Some var« is set to `50`, but when you add a filter callback to `change_this_var`, then you can **get, modify and return** the value.

### Excercise

Here's an example, based on your question, that **gets** the variable as parameter in the function definition (the definition of the "filter callback"-function). It then **modifies** (in case - we use conditional tags here) it and **returns** it.

```
add_filter( 'excerpt_length', 'wpse61271_custom_excerpt_length', PHP_INT_MAX -1 );
function wpse61271_custom_excerpt_length( $length ) 
{
    return ( 
       is_front_page()
       XOR is_home()
    )
       ? 50
       : $length;
}
```

Comment: thank you - worked perfectly. I need to learn this stuff too, so thanks for explaining. Not sure if I am allowed to vote up your answer yet, but I would.