# Custom Excerpts Per Page

Tags: excerpt

I'm trying to set up a specific page to use a specific number of characters in an excerpt. I tried using this code, but it broke the site:

```
function wpse61271_custom_excerpt_length( $length ) 
{
    if ( 
       is_front_page()
       XOR is_home()
    )
       return 50;

    // return default length
    return $length;
}
add_filter( 'excerpt_length', 'wpse61271_custom_excerpt_length', 999 );
```

Is there an alternate bit of code that could work better?

EDIT: Here's the full loop, in case that helps:

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2></a>
                        <div class="storyVideo">
                            <p><?php the_post_video(); ?></p>
                        </div><!--/.storyVideo-->
                        <div class="storyExcerpt">
                            <?php
                                function wpse61271_custom_excerpt_length( $length ) 
                                {
                                    if ( 
                                       is_front_page()
                                       XOR is_home()
                                    )
                                       return 50;

                                    // return default length
                                    return $length;
                                }
                                add_filter( 'excerpt_length', 'wpse61271_custom_excerpt_length', 999 );
                            ?>
                            <p><a class="button" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read More</a></p>
                        </div><!--/.storyExcerpt-->
                        <div style="clear:both;"></div>
                    <?php endwhile; ?>
                    <?php if(function_exists('wp_paginate')) {
                        wp_paginate();
                    } ?>
```

Comment: Changed the wording so I'm no longer asking for a plugin. I don't get why asking for a plugin is against the rules, it seems perfectly on topic to me. I'm trying to solve a WordPress problem, a plugin may solve it.

Comment: Plugin recommendations are explicitly off-topic per the [FAQ](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: That's great, but they shouldn't be.

Comment: As for your question:  Does your code work if you switch the `XOR` to a `||`?  (Also, how did the code "break the site"?)

Comment: Can you show us the PHP error you get? (wonder why are you using XOR)

Comment: A plugin recommendation falls into the "please do my homework for me" category-- aka, "does not show any research effort". Why should I, or anyone else, search the plugin repository for you? Or spend time searching the web for something that probably isn't going to meet your precise requirements anyway?  But back to the topic: How does this break the site? That is a pretty strict condition you have but I can't get anything to actually break.

Comment: I get that that's the case sometimes, but in many cases, people do do research, and just can't find the right plugin for the job (like my case). It doesn't give any kind of PHP error, it seems to "eat" other code on the page somehow. View this page for a demo: http://lifemattersmedia.weblinx.us/category/stories/

Changing XOR to || didn't fix it.

Comment: I copied this script from another question (http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/61271/custom-excerpt-length-on-home-page?rq=1), so I'm not sure what, if anything, needs to be changed. I'm pretty new to WordPress.

Comment: Where in your theme/plugin did you paste the code?

Comment: Where the excerpt should display, within a loop. See the original post, just posted the whole loop.

Comment: Remove it from there, and add it instead into the file in your theme called `functions.php`.  (If `functions.php` doesn't exist -- it should, but if it doesn't -- create it.)

Comment: Alright, so how do I actually call it on the page, then?

Comment: If it's in the `functions.php` file, you won't need to call it.  Stuff in `functions.php` is automatically loaded as required.  See the [Codex page](https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development#Functions_File) on Theme Development for more info.

Comment: So then that's going to affect every excerpt? I need it to affect only excerpts on that specific page.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9200/discussion-between-pat-j-and-rev)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution that should do what you want (per your questions in comments and chat):

#### Functions.php

```
function wpse102641_custom_excerpt_length( $length ) 
{
    // assuming your category is called "Stories"
    if ( is_category(  'Stories' ) ) {
       return 50;
    }

    // return default length
    return $length;
}
add_filter( 'excerpt_length', 'wpse102641_custom_excerpt_length', 999 );
```

#### References

Codex:

- [`is_category()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_category)